# What's the difference between 遇到 and 碰到?

Tags: mandarin, expressions, synonyms

Both 遇到 and 碰到 can be translated to "come across/run into" in those sentences:

> 遇到大学同学了。
>
> 碰到大学同学了。

What's the difference between 遇到 and 碰到?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Generally the same.

"碰" is more informal than "遇" when used followed by "到" or "见" to form "碰/遇到" and "碰/遇见"

Another difference is that "碰" is more 'physical' as a verb than "遇", E.g.

- "碰" is literally "touch", also with meaning "collide" as in "碰撞".
- "遇" is more similar to "meet" as in "遇见" or "being through" as in "境遇".

Answer (score 10):

I like to think of 碰到 as the equivalent of the English ["bumped into"](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bumped_into)

And 遇到 as the English ["came across"](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/come_across) or ["encountered"](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/encountered).

The later being more formal and first being more oral in both the English and Chinese.

Comment: This is the most correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

I got the impression that 碰到 implies a more unexpected or accidental meeting than 遇到. I can't find any references to back that up, though. They both seem to imply some element of chance or unpredictability.

Answer (score -2):

In this case, they have the same meaning！

```
 遇到大学同学了。


 碰到大学同学了。
```